# MongoDB Collection data to Php table issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I have php code for displaying MongoDB collection data to php tablle, when i run it it doesn't show any output,

please be kind enough to sort this

Here my code

```
<?php

        $m = new MongoClient();
        $db = $m->selectDB('MapData');
        $collection = new MongoCollection($db,'ETom4');

        $cursor = $collection->find();
        //echo "<html><head><body>";
        echo "<table>";
        foreach($cursor as $doc) {
             echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Marks'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>"; 
             echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<table>";
        //echo "</html></head></body>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `as $doc` instead of `as $row` here.

```
    foreach($cursor as $doc) {
         echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Marks'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
```

Change it to the variable you need to use, being `$doc` and not `$row`:

```
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('MapData');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db,'ETom4');

    $cursor = $collection->find();
    //echo "<html><head><body>";
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($cursor as $doc) {
         echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $doc['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $doc['Marks'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $doc['value'] . "</td>"; 
         echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<table>";
    //echo "</html></head></body>";
```

---

**HTML stickler:**

You also commented out 2 lines which you're including your markup inside `<head></head>` and have placed `</html>` before `</body>`.

```
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('MapData');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db,'ETom4');

    $cursor = $collection->find();
    //echo "<html><head></head><body>";
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($cursor as $doc) {
         echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $doc['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $doc['Marks'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $doc['value'] . "</td>"; 
         echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<table>";
    //echo "</body></html>";
```

The syntax/structure is:

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>

 <body>
 ...
 </body>
</html>
```

You can also add `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line.

- (Modern-day) Web browsers require a valid doc type.
- Consult: https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

---

**Footnotes:**

You also need to make sure of the columns' letter-case.

They are case-sensitive when iterating over rows in a loop.

Therefore `Name` and `name` would be considered different.

If (any or all of) the above still doesn't work for you, then you may have errors somewhere.

- **So, check for errors.**

Comment: @Kavinda  please check your all questions answers and try to mark the answers which are correct.Thanks.